# Address suggestions while searching offline SKMAPS

Tags: ios, skmaps

I am using MultiStep offline search in SKMaps. I have a search bar in my application, where a user can type an address to search in an offline downloaded package say California. While writing an address in the search bar , I want to show address suggestions to user. Is this possible with Skobbler? I could not find any api provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current APi there is not "one line search" (type the whole address in a single line) and no out-of-the-box typeahead.

You can implement the typeahead by using the user's input as a search term for the multiline search - http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios#sec20 - you will have to decide if that term is a city  or a street in a particular city for this to properly work.

On another note - we are working on a new geocoding implementation that would provide one line search and typeahead - this should be out in Q1 or Q2 2015

Comment: yes, so for now i would have to use Google Place API to get autocomplete search.Thanks for the quick reply.